# ¿Cómo hago una petición HTTP con Authorization: Bearer <Token>?

Tags: nodejs, http, https

La realidad es que no tengo mucha idea de cómo hacer una petición HTTP pero es que necesito obtener unos datos para los cuales preciso hacer una petición GET y autorizarme con un Token, mi pregunta es ¿qué es lo que debería incluir en el objeto `options`? y si alguien me pudiera dar una idea de como hacerlo en nodejs lo agradeceria.

La ubiación de la API es: `https://ubiquity.api.blockdaemon.com/v2/{platform}/{network}/txs` y esta es la [documentacion](https://ubiquity.docs.blockdaemon.com/#operation/GetTxs) del endpoint que estoy tratando de consumir.

Por ahora mi código es este:

```javascript
const http = require('http');

const options = {
    hostname: 'ubiquity.api.blockdaemon.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/v2/{ethereum}/{mainnet}/txs',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer bd1bILrdTjfAZ19mNxRNCyRGpmWW4ilL2CTvHX3arat4BO',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
};

http.get(options, (res) => {
    //  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    //  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        const datos = JSON.parse(d);
        //process.stdout.write(datos);
        console.log(datos);
    });

}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Al ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Si le quito el `JSON.parse()` me devuelve un `Buffer` con muchas letras y números que no se que indican.

Comment: Quita las llaves `{}`, no son necesarias pero en la documentación se muestran a modo indicativo, es decir, que todo lo que se encuentra denotado por las llaves (incluyendo las mismas), debe ser reemplazado por un valor como si fuera una etiqueta. En este caso `{platform}` por `etherum` y `{network}` por `mainnet`; así pasas de `'/v2/{platform}/{network}/txs'` a `'/v2/ethereum/mainnet/txs'`. De ahí que obtengas el error de token inesperado. Por lo demás, el objeto de opciones parece estar correcto.

Comment: Como sugerencia y asumiendo que el token que pones en el ejemplo es tuyo y es el que utilizas, no deberías proporcionarlo y colocar en su lugar alguno ficticio o simplemente usar la palabra `token` en lugar de colocar el token real, se entiende y así evitas que hagan un mal uso del mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, hice ese cambio y me dio el error 400 "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port"  por lo que volví a hacer la llamada pero esta vez en https y funciono correctamente. Y por cierto el token es el mío pero modificado para dar el ejemplo, gracias por la aclaración!